# Как научить nautilus заменять только более старые файлы при копировании?

Tags: debian

Как научить nautilus заменять только более старые файлы при копировании?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте rsync -a
Опции могут быть другими в зависимости от того, что вам нужно.
Что касается Наутилуса, то у него есть возможность подключать bash скрипты в контекстное меню.